# Game crashes when using sound.play(url)

Tags: lua, game-engine, ubuntu-18.04, defold

The game crashes when sound.play(url) is triggered.

I am using Defold Version - 1.2.170 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I have raised a detailed bug report [here](https://github.com/defold/defold/issues/4983).

The crash report is as follows:

```
��1.2.1705791ee6d96b87e50eee5acd70abaa4026fefef28Linux5.3.0-59-genericenenINdmenginelibXdmcp.so.6.0.0libXau.so.6.0.0libbsd.so.0.8.7libasound.so.2.0.0libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0libGLX.so.0.0.0libxcb.so.1.1.0librt-2.27.solibsndio.so.6.1libc-2.27.solibgcc_s.so.1libm-2.27.solibstdc++.so.6.0.25libdl-2.27.solibpthread-2.27.solibGLU.so.1.3.1libGL.so.1.0.0libX11.so.6.3.0libopenal.so.1.18.2ld-2.27.so�?�U��]1�]PQ�]�r�]��]pμ]���]�]�4�]�U�]���]��]���]�(�]�H�]�j�]���]`��]���]��]
                                                                        /�?�U��I�]/home/nevin/.Defold/unpack/c08d752f41f670e57c28a238ad8e7eecdfc27833/x86_64-linux/bin/dmengine(+0x2f2f07) [0x55c33fbe2f07]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f5dbe49e890]
```

The crash report file is attached in the github issues page. I am suspecting if the issue is because of any os sound libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of using 24 bit sound as it only supports 16 bit sound. A discussion on adding that to build error has been done, you can follow the discussion in the linked issue on the post.